# Script de BASH controles

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Tengo el siguiente script, al cual se le pasa un directorio y los modificadores d, r, o devuelve la cantidad de hardlinks y su ruta.

Ahora bien, quiero agregarle un control de que si se le pasa el modificar -r y la carpeta esta vacía diga "no hay archivos regulares para mostrar" y si se le pasa el modificar -d y la carpeta esta vacía diga "No se han encontrado archivos (que no sean directorios) para listar en el
directorio"

No lo estoy logrando hacer.
Me ayudan?
Gracias

```
type=''
orden=''
dir='+'

while getopts dro: parametros;
do
case $parametros in
        d)
                dir='^[^d] '
        ;;
        r)
                type='-type f'
        ;;
        o)
                orden='-r'
        ;;

        *)
        echo "Modificador pasado como parámetro incorrecto. Solo se aceptan -d, -r y -o." >&2
        exit 5
        ;;

esac
done





if [ -r $directorio ] && [ -w $directorio ]
then
                if [  $(find ${@: -1}  $type -links +0 -ls | tr -s ' '| awk '{print $3,$4,$11}' | egrep $dir | awk '{print $2":"$3}' | sort $orden -k1 | wc -l) -eq 0 ]
                then
                        echo "No se han encontrado archivos de ningún tipo para listar en el directorio $directorio"
                else
                        find ${@: -1}  $type -links +0 -ls | tr -s ' '| awk '{print $3,$4,$11}' | egrep $dir | awk '{print $2":"$3}' | sort $orden -k1
                        exit 0
                fi
else
        echo "No se tienen los permisos necesarios para acceder al directorio $directorio y desplegar el listado"
        exit 3
fi
```

Comment: sugiero dejar solamente el código imprescindible. Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es mirar si una carpeta dada está vacía, ¿no? Entonces todo el resto será innecesario para la pregunta